# What's wrong in my python code?

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import os
import string, sys

a='sys.argv[1]'
b='sys.argv[2]'
os.system("scp a:/export/home/sample/backup.sql  b:/home/rushi/abc.sql")
```

it's giving the following error:

```
ssh: a: node name or service name not known
```

Comment: At least try to write English, not LOLSPEAK, okay? Further, what *is* wrong with this code? Do you get errors? Does something not work?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: i hv written the error above...can u plz look into that error ..

Comment: the code is supposed to accept the username and machinename as the command line argurment..eg root@10.45.34.33. and transfer the files between two given commandline arguements

Comment: so you want to pass in the _user name_ and _machine name_ into your script as parameters and transfer the files (whatever they may be) between them? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is wrong:

1. `a` and `b` don't have second and third values of `sys.argv` as you might've intended
2. `a` and `b` are not related to the `os.system` call
3. you're using `os.system`
4. you're importing module that you're not using

How to fix:

1. use `a = sys.argv[1]` without the quotes, same for `b`.
2. use `.format` method or similar `%` to format a string
3. have a look at `subprocess` module
4. don't import `string`

Answer (score 2):

the very first character of that first line should be `#`.

Answer (score 1):

You have bound the names "a" and "b" to the arguments passed on the command line (actually, you would have done that if you had removed the quotes after the equal sign,).

But in the command that you are executing, you are NOT using them, you are using the literal "a" and "b" drives.
This is a dangerous approach because you risk injections. In any case, if you trust the source of the inputs, you can escape the values for a and b, something like

```
os.system("scp %s:/export/home/sample/backup.sql  %s:/home/rushi/abc.sql" % (a, b))
```

This is not the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be changed to this

```
a=sys.argv[1]
b=sys.argv[2]
```

Since right now you are treating sys.argv[1] as strings by adding quotes

also you want to do this:

```
os.system("scp %s:/export/home/sample/backup.sql  %s:/home/rushi/abc.sql" % (a,b) )
```

so that you add the variables to the string you are trying to call with os.system

Comment: its now giving following error:Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection

Comment: You need to include a username and password. I assume 'a' is on your local machine and 'b' is remote. the remote address should look like username@something.com:/home/rushi/abc.sql

Comment: If you need to use authentication you are going to have to add an identity file containing your private key. Enter 'man scp' to get the docs for that command or here: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/scp.htm